# How to get Sycthing GUI and register if missed it

Tags: gui, sync

I am a new Ubuntu user so I'm little bit lost.

I installed Syncthing by following these steps: https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-and-use-syncthing-on-ubuntu-18-04/

I still only manages to get Syncthing that is opening only on browser and I don't know why. Is there not a version that doesn't use browser?

I also somehow missed setting the username and password and don't know how to do it. How safe it is to use Syncthing without them?

## Update

I found GUI!

Comment: Hi. I'm pretty sure that Syncthing only have a web GUI accessible via browser. This is pretty normal with these kind of applications, since it provides platform independency. Regarding user and password, the Syncthing docs state that the web GUI by default is reachable from localhost only. So under normal circumstances it should not be an issue.

Comment: Syncthing is pretty [well documented](https://docs.syncthing.net/). You might also be able to get specific help on [Syncthing forums](https://forum.syncthing.net/).

Comment: Thank you both very much!

Comment: Good to hear you found the GUI. What was the issue? Your mistake or some technical workaround?

Comment: The issue was that I am new Ubuntu user and didn't figure out first that I could search Syncthing on Ubuntu Software :)